# Why did an Orc stronghold mine let me mine stone indefinitely?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I found an Orc stronghold, but wasn't allowed in because I'm not an orc and haven't proven myself. However, when I was leaving, I walked by the orc's blacksmith and noticed that there was a place to mine. Surprisingly, it kept going and I ended up just letting my character mine nonstop while I was watching TV. When it finally stopped, I had 4,000 quarrel stone!

Why did that happen? I thought I wouldn't be allowed to mine in an Orc stronghold unless I've proven myself worthy.

Comment: 1) This is really unclear. 2) How did you automate your mining of the ore? 3) Ore veins usually deplete IIRC

Comment: Sorry I hit x to mine and instead of giving me a few ore and then be depleted it kept going saying 4 ore added over and over and it didn't stop or deplete until I had 4,000 ore. Once i clicked to mine it and I realized it wasn't stopping I just watched tv for about a half an hour until it said it was deplete and I had 4,000 ore

Comment: Sounds like a bug since you were on PS3/4. Usually you get 3 ore from the vein before it runs out, and then replenishes after 10 days. There are mods on PC for this sort of thing, but on Playstation it will be a bug.

Comment: @KallumTanton that's what I figured, bc I've never had that happen before even when I went searching for mines. I've noticed too that ever since I started playing on this version (PS4 I previously had the one for PS3) and I'm guessing when a game's this elaborate it's bound to have a few bugs, especially since they've added so much to the new one, bc I've noticed a few things like it's easier for me to steal right beside someone than sneaking around, my horse turned on me but I could ride him but whenever I got down the horse went nuts&once I walk up on a group of guards squatting in a huddle

Comment: I took a pic of the guards if want to see it it's rather funny

Comment: What kind of ore was it? Clay and Stone deposits never deplete.

Comment: I got 4,000 Quarrel stone ore before it depleted

Comment: Stone usually comes in greater amount (near infinite) because it's one of the main ingredients for building houses in Hearthfire. Along with clay and logs (not firewood). It's not a ore vein you've been hitting, but a stone quarry.

Comment: Given that the OP has informed us that the materiel being mined is Quarried Stone which has an infinite supply (though the depletion mentioned by the OP suggest *near-infinite*), that is clearly the answer to the question - would one of the users who commented this kindly add it as an answer?

Comment: @KallumTanton if I was able to or knew how I would. However this app is extremely hard for me to navigate,and my questions as to how to use it or search for answers has been unanswered. If you or anyone else wouldn't mind giving me a moment of your time to help me out with learning this app better I would be forever grateful! Let me know and I will give u my cellphone # so we don't have to go back & forth on this feed.  Thanks again !!!!!

Comment: If you'd like to chat about this please go to the chat room I've created: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61107/writing-answers

Comment: @KallumTanton  which room

Answer (score 1):

You can Mine inside an orc stronghold IF

1) You are an Orc

2) You helped them

3) You killed all of them

The first option is open when you have created a character, choose orc, and then you just have to go to their strongholds for ores.

The second one, you have to prove yourself to various quests, it may be battling giants, fist fighting with the orc leader, etc... (I was granted entrance when I finished the quest where you may get the best warhammer in the game)

The last one, I think is not lore friendly, but once you get inside the mines without their permission (they will give their warnings and ask you to leave) they will attack you.